# Why was uranium mined in the 1500s, but only "discovered" in 1789?

Tags: science, 16th-century, historical-techniques

[This Guardian article](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2022/dec/15/dismantling-sellafield-epic-task-shutting-down-decomissioned-nuclear-site?utm_source=pocket-newtab-global-en-GB) talks about how uranium was mined at the beginning of the 1500s. The Guardian is a pretty reputable newspaper as far as I’m aware, so I am willing to believe them. Out of curiosity, I attempted to find out why anyone would mine uranium in the 1500s. A quick google tells me it was only defined as an element by Martin Klaproth in 1789, and the article mentions that uranium’s radioactivity wasn’t discovered until around 1896.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium#Pre-discovery_use) mentions ceramic glazing, but also mentions it has been mined since the Roman empire, so I'm not sure what to believe there.

So what did people think they were mining before this? Was it just some kind of heavy stuff? Was there any link between the chemical and people falling ill? Or was it just in such small quantities or handled so little that no one noticed?

Comment: [The uranium mineral pitchblende was extracted in the 1500s for the production of colouring agents used in the glassmaking industry](https://www.intechopen.com/chapters/57723)

Comment: Please cite the "infamous Wikipedia" page  is it [WIkipedia:Uranium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium#History)  If so, the answer seems to be in the difference between "isolated" and "discovered"

Comment: People would be falling ill from many things, isolating the cause would have been difficult.  In 1500 most earthenware crockery would have been lead glazed, any stoneware glazes containing potash-feldspar would have been radioactive due to potassium-40.

Comment: I have a vague memory that certain multi-colored plastic dishware sets in the U.S. in the late 1950s had the orange-ish colored one made orange by some uranium compound... Consistent with historical use in color.

Comment: Are you simply asking if the Guardian article was sloppy about an ancillary detail?

Comment: Limestone was "mined" by ancient Egyptians. Calcium was "discovered" in the 1800s. Same pattern for silicon in the stone age tools or aluminum in the clay pottery.

Comment: The guardian is famously weak on technical, scientific details. In this case it fails to distinguish between mining "uranium" and a *mineral* that contains uranium. Many elements were not isolated or recognised until the 20th century with only a few being recognised as early as the 18th century (including uranium).

Comment: *"were minding"* → *"were mining"*

Comment: @matt_black - the guardian, or the Guardian?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It is more commonly referred to as the Grauniad due to the common typos by its subeditors.

Comment: @matt_black - that's about 50 years out of date. Frequent typographical errors during the age of manual typesetting led Private Eye magazine to dub the paper the "Grauniad" in the 1960s, a nickname still used occasionally by the editors for self-mockery. The others who use the term are self-identifying as Daily Mail readers.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I think the term is still useful to describe the Guardian's casual attitude to scientific and technical stats and facts. And I take offence at being described as a Daily Fail reader. ;-)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Uranium oxide *in the form of the mineral pitchblende* was known and mined - as [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium#Pre-discovery_use) says. So the short answer is that as far as anyone in the 1500s was concerned, they were mining pitchblende and using it to make things turn yellow - they had no reason to care about where pitchblende came from.

> The use of uranium in its natural oxide form dates back to at least the year 79 CE, when it was used in the Roman Empire to add a yellow color to ceramic glazes. ...  Starting in the late Middle Ages, pitchblende was extracted from the Habsburg silver mines in Joachimsthal, Bohemia (now Jáchymov in the Czech Republic), and was used as a coloring agent in the local glassmaking industry. [WP]

Discovering what pitchblende itself was composed of did not come until Klaproth (or possibly, per Wikipedia, until Péligot in 1841 - Klaproth thought he had identified it, but Péligot was the first to extract pure uranium).

This situation was not unique to uranium; [cobalt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobalt#History) ores have been used for millennia to colour things, but the underlying element was not identified until the mid-18th century.

Comment: [We are mostly water](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ugly%20bag%20of%20mostly%20water) and drink it all the time, but hydrogen was only recognized as  such in 1766.

Comment: @Spencer - Philosophical question: does that make a well a "hydrogen mine"?

Comment: @T.E.D. Just add sodium and you have a hydrogen gusher!

Comment: @T.E.D. Only if you intend to extract the hydrogen, and that's why it's an anachronism to claim that anyone "mined uranium" in the 16th century.

Comment: Fun fact about those silver mines in Joachimsthal - coins produced there were called "Joachimsthalers", later shortened to "thalers"; this is where the English word "dollar" comes from.

Comment: @T.E.D. No, since liquid mines are called wells, even when they're oil or natural gas and not water.  But if you had an ice cave...

Comment: @Bobson A frozen lake was the more common source, I think. It used to be quite common to 'mine' ice out of frozen lakes and such and then store the ice blocks in an ice house where they could remain frozen for most or all of the year and be used either for refrigerating food or for chilling drinks. (Though, if I remember correctly, the latter was reserved mostly for the rather wealthy, considering how labor-intensive it was to get the ice, especially if transportation of any significant distance was required.) (Edit: Wiki suggests the practice goes back to at least 1780 B.C. in Mesopotamia.)

Comment: @T.E.D. No, it’s a hydrogen rig.

Comment: @skyler There's a decent PBS special on nuclear energy called "Twisting the Dragon's Tail" hosted by Derek Muller (of youtube Veritasium fame) which talks about these mines.  I forget the exact details, but the miners called the Uranium ore 'bad luck rock' or something because it wwas associated with the end of the silver seam IIRC.